# Detect keyup after a click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect a modifier key keyup event after a mouse click.

Some background: the mouse click being detected is being captured by the Sketchfab viewer API as documented [here](https://sketchfab.com/developers/viewer/functions#api-click). The API does not return whether any modifier keys were being pressed at the moment of the click.

However I would like the UI to do different things depending on whether modifier keys are being pressed.

I have tried to detect and keep track of modifier keys down/up events like this:

```
var c = {} // this is actually a vue.js object
c.keyModifiers = { ctrlKey: false, altKey: false, shiftKey: false }

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if ([16, 17, 18].includes(event.keyCode) ) {
            Object.keys(c.keyModifiers)
              .forEach(k => {
                   c.keyModifiers[k] = event[k]
            })
        }
}, true);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if ([16, 17, 18].includes(event.keyCode) ) {
            Object.keys(c.keyModifiers)
                .forEach(k => {
                     c.keyModifiers[k] = event[k]
                 })
        }
}, true);
```

but the keyup event is not detected anymore after the click (keydown works great).

Other things I've tried/thought of:

- detecting click anywhere in the window: doesn't seem to work probably because the Sketchfab viewer is an iframe
- having a setInterval loop checking if the key is pressed: there doesn't seem to be a way to do that

What can I do to detect if a modifier key is pressed in this case?

Comment: Why is keyup important? You get the same codes.

Comment: Because I need to know whether the mod key is pressed when the click happens, and there is no other way I know of doing it

Comment: Actually the events have slightly different results but they both will detect mod keys, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70805058/2813224).

Comment: Have you tried accessing the native `window.event` from the handler you pass to the library? If that library just synchronously wraps (mouse) events, it should be accessible (though hack-ish) and conveniently provide you  `altKey` / `shiftKey` / `metaKey` properties.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: Anyway, symptom "keydown event listener fires, but keyup does not after I click something" sounds like that click silently focused different document. Aren't there *more* iframes in play after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.keyCode` and just about everything else has been deprecated in favor for [`.key`](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). The method [`.getModifierState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState) will help determine mod keys.

***Details are in the example below***

```js
let keyDn = {};
let keyUp = {};

const viewKey = e => {
  const mods = ['Alt', 'Control', 'Shift'];
  let KEY = e.type === 'keydown' ? keyDn : keyUp;
  KEY.event = e.type;
  KEY.repeat = e.repeat;
  KEY.key = e.key;
  KEY.mod = mods.flatMap(mod => e.getModifierState(mod) ? [mod] : []);
  console.log(KEY);
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", viewKey);
document.addEventListener("keyup", viewKey);
```

```css
:root {
  font: 1ch/1.5 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  font-size: 2.75ch;
}

code {
  font-family: Consolas;
  color: #930;
}

kbd {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 1.5px 3px;
  border: 0.5px grey solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #000;
  background: #ccc;
}

ol,
ul {
  margin-left: -25px
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Click here with mouse, finger, or any other device or appendage </li>
  <li>Click any keys on keyboard
    <ul>
      <li>Including mod keys<br> ex. <code>"Shift"</code> is <kbd>Any Key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>
      </li>
      <li>Also repeating keys<br> if <code>true</code> means user kept his/her/it's finger on the key
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Review the console
    <ul>
      <li>There will be 2 objects: <code>keyDn</code> and <code>keyUp</code></li>
      <li>The <code>mod</code> property is an array value<br>ex. <code>['Shift', 'Control']</code> is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Keep in mind these 2 objects will be overwriting their values with every keystroke</li>
</ol>
```